# How to stop if Criteria isn't found in autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, autofilter

My code gather info based on a different file that's just data and copies and pastes the data in my main folder.  It goes of the Dim which I have set to a range B1 but right now if the data in B1 isn't found in the Field I'm looking for it simply copies all the blank cells into the main folder.

I would need it to stop if the Variable isn't located in the field

```
Sub Sheet01()
'
' Sheet01 Macro
'

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim varField            As String
varField = Range("B1")
With ActiveSheet
  Range("Q3:AA2999").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "V:\Training\Share\Intraday Training Tracker\Agent Suite Raw        Data\AgentSuite - Current.xlsx"
Sheets("ActivityDetails").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$197561").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "CS", "Cons", "Medium", "MobOutbound", "NC", _
    "PMobile", "Personal Team", "ST", "SmBu", "Tech", _
    "Tech Support "), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$197561").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Complete", "Eligible", "NotScheduled", "Processing", "Scheduled"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$197561").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="1"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$197561").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=varField
```

Currently I don't get any error message .

Comment: hi. if Range("B1")<>"" then RUN CRITERIA CODE else DO NOTHING. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You will not get an error if the filter does not find any values.  I would suggest that after you open the workbook and select the sheet (I suggest looking up how to avoid Activate/Select) that you do a `Range.Find` to determine if the `varField` exists.  If it does not, then you can exit the Sub or do something else.

```
Set FindRng = Sheets("ActivityDetails").Columns(1).Find(varField)
If FindRng Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```